# Sqlite database encryption with wxsqlite3 run time error

Tags: c++, encryption, sqlite, wxwidgets, dynamic-linking

I downloaded the prebuilt binaries from [here](https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3/releases)(wxSQLite3 3.5.9) and also I downloaded the `sqlite3.h` file version 3.21.0, I added the header file and `.dll` and `.lib` file to my project.

I copied the 32 bit version of dll and lib file, and copied them in my solution and also added the `.lib` file to `Additional Dependencies` in `Linker->Input` in project properties.

I created this sample application with C++:

```
#define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_open("test1.db", &db);

    sqlite3_key(
        db, /* Database to be rekeyed */
        "test", sizeof("test") /* The key, and the length of the key in bytes */
    );

    std::string createQuery =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ipaddr       TEXT, username TEXT, useradd TEXT, userphone INTEGER, age INTEGER, "
        "time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW()));";

    sqlite3_stmt* createStmt;
    std::cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, createQuery.c_str(), createQuery.size(), &createStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Table Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(createStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;

    string insertQuery =
        "INSERT INTO items (time, ipaddr,username,useradd,userphone,age) VALUES('7:30', '192.187.27.55', 'vivekanand', 'kolkatta', '04456823948', 74);";
    // WORKS!
    sqlite3_stmt* insertStmt;
    cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, insertQuery.c_str(), insertQuery.size(), &insertStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this program I get this error at run time:
[image: Run time error]

But If I comment this section of code

```
sqlite3_key(
            db, /* Database to be rekeyed */
            "test", sizeof("test") /* The key, and the length of the key in bytes */
        );
```

It works just fine, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you buy the encryption extension for the SQLite? It is not a free product and not part of the main SQLite API.

Comment: there is an open source implementation here https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3

Comment: which I think is just a wrapper around the SQLite extension. Which means you still should pay for the extension itself. Just ask Ulrich about it on the github project. It is just like wxSQLite3 is a wrapper around SQLite API.

Comment: @Igor How does this repository claims to be open source sqlite encryption library? https://github.com/rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption
it uses portion of wxSqlite(basically made compilation more easiy)

Comment: @Igor In the description of repo it says `wxSQLite3 - SQLite3 database wrapper for wxWidgets (including SQLite3 encryption extension)`

Comment: I didn't see any reference of this link in the OP and I never saw that link before. I do know that the official encryption for SQLite is "paid" software. And you didn't mention anything about either of those. Let me look at the link you referenced.

Comment: it is a wrapper, which means in order to use you have to have an actual extension. Just ask Ulrich about it on wxSQLite3 repo or on the forums.wxwidgets.org.

Comment: Just for clarification: [wxSQLite3](https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3) is a thin wrapper for the [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) library for [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org) based applications.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quick enough to edit my previous comment. Here some additions to it:

However, wxSQLite3 includes the implementation of an encryption extension that is based on the SQLite encryption extension API and that can also be used independently of the wxWidgets wrapper. While the official [SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](https://www.sqlite.org/see) is not free, the encryption extension coming with wxSQLite3 is free. Pre-compiled binaries (DLLs) are provided for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C/C++ code seems to be alright. And if the test application could be compiled correctly, obviously a valid link library was used. However, the runtime error message indicates that the correct DLL was not loaded.

This indicates that the pre-compiled SQLite DLL was not copied into the same directory where the executable of the test application resides, or it was not in the search path of the application. However, some SQLite DLL was found in the search path, but most likely an "official" SQLite DLL that does not include the encryption extension.

Make sure that the SQLite DLL that includes the encryption extension is accessible by the test application.

The pre-compiled binaries from the wxSQLite3 releases definitely include the entry points sqlite3_key and sqlite3_rekey.